# Wordpress: Zopim showing Curl issue while curl is installed

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Stuck in a issue after successful installation of zopim, its showing error to check curl installation, while curl is already installed on my live server, what's can be issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall the plugin from your local computer if you have already installed and if you're using the lite version of zopim , this error is thrown cause you can only use in one place with the same account !